# Android SensorManager error in LogCat

Tags: android, logcat, android-sensors, sensormanager

I have a problem with the sensor manager and errors in the logcat.
When I register the listener with this line :

```
sensorMgr.registerListener(this, sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

I recieve theses lines in the logcat with three errors.

```
06-07 20:52:42.419: D/SensorManager(9215): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 1
06-07 20:52:42.419: D/SensorManager(9215): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 2
06-07 20:52:42.419: D/SensorManager(9215): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 3
06-07 20:52:42.419: D/SensorManager(9215): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 4
06-07 20:52:42.419: D/SensorManager(9215): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 5
06-07 20:52:42.419: D/SensorManager(9215): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 6
06-07 20:52:42.419: D/SensorManager(9215): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 0
06-07 20:52:42.419: E/SensorManager(9215): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= BMA220 delay= 200000 Listener= fr.rocknscrum.liseronmobile.MainActivity@40520980
06-07 20:52:42.419: E/SensorManager(9215): =======>>>Sensor Thread RUNNING <<<========
06-07 20:52:42.429: E/SensorManager(9215): reg :: handle = 0
```

It works great, there is no problem but how can I avoid these errors ?

PS : I don't use the deprecated version.

Comment: I think it is normal internal logs ..... what is problem in that?

Comment: Is this on device or in emulator (and if in emulator which API level)?

Comment: It's not internal log, it's marked as an error in red.
It's on the device with android 2.3.3 or 3.2 (with juste the second line error). And on the simulator I have no error.

Comment: Simulators don't have sensors ... This is prefectly normal ...

Comment: Yes but why an error comes on real devices ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an error, this is a normal behavior, they marked it as error by mistake. You can run it on an ICS device and see the same log line in a "debug" log-type.