# SensorManager "thread start" Error

Tags: android, sensormanager

I am trying to make an app that uses the accelerometer to detect movements of the user and trigger  some events. The app needs a lot of work but every time I run the app in my phone I get the ERROR "thread start" but nothing seems to happen.

Here is the LogCat:

```
    04-15 17:46:21.380: E/BANANA(2516): Before sensor
    04-15 17:46:21.380: D/SensorManager(2516): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K2DM delay= 200000 Listener= com.example.rockpaperaccelerate.UseSensor@413cdf98
    04-15 17:46:21.380: E/SensorManager(2516): thread start
    04-15 17:46:21.520: E/BANANA(2516): AFter sensor
    04-15 17:46:21.680: D/libEGL(2516): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
    04-15 17:46:21.800: D/libEGL(2516): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_rhea.so
    04-15 17:46:21.960: D/BRCM_EGL(2516): eglCreateContext() config: 18 context: 0x12e0a0, VC context 1, Thread 2516
    04-15 17:46:21.960: D/BRCM_EGL(2516): eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x2aa080, VC surface: 1, Thread: 2516
    04-15 17:46:21.960: D/BRCM_EGL(2516): eglMakeCurrent(0x12e0a0, 0x2aa080, 0x2aa080) Thread: 2516
    04-15 17:46:21.980: D/OpenGLRenderer(2516): Enabling debug mode 0
    04-15 17:46:22.441: D/CLIPBOARD(2516): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
```

And this is the activity where everything takes place:

```
public class UseSensor extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSensor;
    public int choice;
    public WebView myWebView1;
    public WebView myWebView2;
    public TextView myTextView;
    public String louts[]={"rock","paper","scissors"};
    public int i=0;
    public float gravity[]={0,0,0}; 
    public float linear_acceleration[]={0,0,0};

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rock_paper_accelerate_with_sensors);
        Log.e("BANANA","Before sensor");

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


        Log.e("BANANA","AFter sensor");


    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio1:
                if (checked)
                    // player chose rock
                    choice=1;

                break;              
            case R.id.radio2:
                if (checked)
                    // player chose paper
                    choice=2;

                break;
            case R.id.radio3:
                if (checked)
                    // player chose scissors
                    choice=3;

                break;  
        }



    }

public void checkWin(int choice){

        Random generator = new Random();
        int machine = generator.nextInt( 3 )+1;
        setContentView(R.layout.show_results);
        myWebView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        switch (machine){
        case 1: myWebView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.jpg");
        break;
        case 2: myWebView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.jpg");
        break;
        case 3: myWebView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/3.jpg");
        break;
        }

        switch (choice){
        case 1: myWebView2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.jpg");
        break;
        case 2: myWebView2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.jpg");
        break;
        case 3: myWebView2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/3.jpg");
        break;
        }

        if (choice==machine){
            myTextView.setText("This is a tie!");
        }
        else if ((choice==3 && machine==2)||(choice==2 && machine==1)||(choice==1 && machine==3)){
            myTextView.setText("You Win!");
        }
        else{
            myTextView.setText("You Lose!");
        }
        Button myButton =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i=0;
                Intent intent= new Intent(v.getContext(), UseSensor.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


        final float alpha = (float) 0.8;

        gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
        gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
        gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

        linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
        linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
        linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];

          if (linear_acceleration[1]<-4.0){
             if(i<3){
                 int findId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.rockpaperaccelerate:layout/" + louts[i], null, null);
                 setContentView(findId);
                 i=i+1;}

              if (i==3){
                  mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
                  i=0;
                  checkWin(choice);
              }
          }


    }


}
```

Could it be a false positive like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938131/android-sensormanager-error-in-logcat) case or am I doing something wrong.The activity continues without stopping. In my main activity that calls UseSensor I use SensorManager again.
The snippet of the code is:

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
         if (mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) != null){
              // Success! There's an accelerometer sensor       
             Intent intent= new Intent(this,UseSensor.class);
             startActivity(intent);

         }
```

Does this have to do with the Error?

Thank you for your time.

----------EDIT------------------------

The error remains but it only appears the first time I run the app from eclipse.If I stop the app and run it again from the home screen of my phone it does not appear.The app stops working sometimes but without giving me any other errors. I changed my code slightly adding another if

```
if(choice !=0){
          if (linear_acceleration[1]<-4.0){
             if(i<3){
                 int findId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.rockpaperaccelerate:layout/" + louts[i], null, null);
                 setContentView(findId);
                 i=i+1;}

              if (i==3){
                  mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

                  i=0;
                  checkWin(choice);
              }
          }
        }
```

I also tried what Lukas suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088302/sensormanager-thread-start-error/23089612#23089612) with no luck.I also implemented another version of my app that has only one activity and the problem remains. The only thing that happens is that ,sometime the app stops working without any other logCat errors

Second implementation

```
public class RockPaper3 extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {


    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSensor;
    public int choice=0;
    public ImageView myImage1,myImage2; 
    public TextView myTextView;
    public String louts[]={"rock","paper","scissors"};
    public int i=0;
    public float gravity[]={0,0,0}; 
    public float linear_acceleration[]={0,0,0};
    public boolean withSensor=true;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
             if (mSensor != null){
                  // Success! There's an accelerometer sensor       
                setContentView(R.layout.rock_paper_accelerate_with_sensors);
                 withSensor=true;


             }
             else {

                    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rock_paper3);
                    withSensor=false;
                  }      


    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio1:
                if (checked)
                    // player chose rock
                    choice=1;

                break;              
            case R.id.radio2:
                if (checked)
                    // player chose paper
                    choice=2;

                break;
            case R.id.radio3:
                if (checked)
                    // player chose scissors
                    choice=3;

                break;  
        }

        if (withSensor==false){
            checkWin(choice);
        }

    }


public void checkWin(int choice){

        Random generator = new Random();
        int machine = generator.nextInt( 3 )+1;
        setContentView(R.layout.show_results);
        myImage1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        myImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        switch (machine){
        case 1: myImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.rock);
        break;
        case 2: myImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.paper);
        break;
        case 3: myImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.scissors);
        break;
        }

        switch (choice){
        case 1: myImage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.rock);
        break;
        case 2: myImage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.paper);
        break;
        case 3: myImage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.scissors);
        break;
        }

        if (choice==machine){
            myTextView.setText("This is a tie!");
        }
        else if ((choice==3 && machine==2)||(choice==2 && machine==1)||(choice==1 && machine==3)){
            myTextView.setText("You Win!");
        }
        else{
            myTextView.setText("You Lose!");
        }
        Button myButton =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i=0;
                Intent intent= new Intent(v.getContext(), RockPaper3.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });


    }


    /*
public void checkWin(int choice){

        Random generator = new Random();
        int machine = generator.nextInt( 3 )+1;
        setContentView(R.layout.show_results);
        myWebView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        switch (machine){
        case 1: myWebView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.jpg");
        break;
        case 2: myWebView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.jpg");
        break;
        case 3: myWebView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/3.jpg");
        break;
        }

        switch (choice){
        case 1: myWebView2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.jpg");
        break;
        case 2: myWebView2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.jpg");
        break;
        case 3: myWebView2.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/3.jpg");
        break;
        }

        if (choice==machine){
            myTextView.setText("This is a tie!");
        }
        else if ((choice==3 && machine==2)||(choice==2 && machine==1)||(choice==1 && machine==3)){
            myTextView.setText("You Win!");
        }
        else{
            myTextView.setText("You Lose!");
        }
        Button myButton =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i=0;
                Intent intent= new Intent(v.getContext(), RockPaper3.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });


    }*/ 

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onPause(); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.rock_paper3, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


        final float alpha = (float) 0.8;

        gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];

        linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];

        if(choice !=0){
          if (linear_acceleration[1]<-4.0){
             if(i<3){
                 int findId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.rockpaperv3:layout/" + louts[i], null, null);
                 setContentView(findId);
                 i=i+1;}

              if (i==3){
                          mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
                          i=0;
                          checkWin(choice);
                        }
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Any ideas what this error means and why my app crashes sometimes without any errors? It occurred to me that it might be too heavy for my phone to handle this poorly written app with all the accelerometer registerings.

---

edit2

The error occurs when I register the listener

---

edit3

After making a lot of changes the app works smoothly but the error is always there.It must be a false alarm when the listener is registered

Comment: make it sense to unregister and re-register your listener? for me, but I dont know your reasons, it make more sense that you dont listen to the events. can you tell me whats the reason that you register and unregister the sensor?

Comment: Actually yes!After catching the if requirement three times ,I want the  app to call checkWin() and allow the user to choose if he wants to keep on playing. I don't think this is the best implementation possible but without it the loop runs all over again if the users moves the phone. Do you thin it has to do with the error? Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: does my solution work?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

in onResume you should register your listener

in onPause you unregister your listener

make a boolean isActive,

and change your onclicklistener to:

```
Button myButton =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i=0;
            isActive=true;
        }
    });
```

change your onSensorChanged to:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(!isActive)return;

    final float alpha = (float) 0.8;

    gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];

    linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];

      if (linear_acceleration[1]<-4.0){
         if(i<3){
             int findId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("com.example.rockpaperaccelerate:layout/" + louts[i], null, null);
             setContentView(findId);
             i=i+1;}

          if (i==3){
      isActive=false;
              i=0;
              checkWin(choice);
          }
      }
}
```

**edit:** or you do it like that code below, **but I really not recomend you that**
change your on click listener to:

```
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i=0;
     mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Lukas I just saw it.Thank you very much for your answer .The problem seems to remain (keep getting that thread start error). Moreover now the app is not working.After I make the choice and start moving it I get a blank screen. 
Just to make sure I added 


 protected void onResume(){

  mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  super.onResume();

 }
 

 protected void onPause(){
  mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
  super.onPause(); 
 }

In your edit you just suggest me to change the onClickListener?

Comment: @MikeVol dont worry about the error. if your problem still exist, i take a look into this evening...?

Comment: it's very mysterious because despite the error things seem to work